# Remove unwanted code in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I'm creating a GUI of [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) in Visual Studio, I sometimes happens to double click on a component and get some auto generated code. To remove this unwanted code, I read somewhere, but I can't remember where, to remove this code you shouldn't delete it, it should be done in some other way to prevent future errors. How do I remove this unwanted code in Visual Studio the right way?

Comment: Generated code is usually necessary.  What code are you trying to get rid of?

Comment: He's talking about those event handlers (often `Click`) that get generated when you double-click on a control in the designer.  They are not necessary until you add behavior.

Comment: Just like Kirk Woll writes. Sometime I miss click on the background or a textlabel and get unwantd event code. And if I delete the code, then part of the design get lost!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, I simply delete the code and nothing bad come out of it. At worse, when you try to build, you'll get an error in the designer.cs saying some code is not found. Simply delete that and everything will work fine.

You can also use Ctrl+Z when you double-click, but it will delete the component you double-clicked on and you'll have to add it again to your form.

Comment: Just go to the Designer after deleting the click handler.  It will detect that the click handler is gone and you will see the screen refresh as it deletes the corresponding line of code in Form1.Designer.cs or whatever file it is in.

Comment: It's a pity Visual Studio does not seem to have a way to lock the automatic event handler generation.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it from the [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) code. For example, if you double click a button, search for `Click="button1_Click"` in your XAML and  delete it.

If you created a Windows Forms project, go to [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools) and open file file `Form.Designer.cs` and from function `InitializeComponent()` delete this line:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Comment: `Extensible application markup language`; it's the designer part of silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the answer is `NO`. Unless there is some specific add-ins from Microsoft (Which I am not aware off) which enables it.

So, You will have to manually delete the unnecessary code which have been auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

Control-Z - it will remove the event handler registration from the YourForm.designer.cs file and also the method from YourForm.cs file.

A warning box will come up as soon as you press Control-Z, just click yes.

Comment: But when I have clicked YES, I sometimes have lost a beig part of my components in the design!

Comment: There is no way to prevent that. Honestly the only to to guarantee only deleting the code you want is to do it manually.